# CASL Vue - How to access $can in route guard

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, casl

I am building a Nuxt app and trying to create a route guard. How can I access `$can` in my Nuxt middleware?

```js
export default (context) => {
    const { route } = context
    route.matched.some((routeRecord) => {
        const options = routeRecord.components.default.options
        console.log(options)
        // should use $can here
        return true
    })
}
```

I import the following in my `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
plugins: [
    { src: '@plugins/vue-can.js' },
]
```

I add `casl` as plugins on the Nuxt $auth module:

```js
auth: {
    plugins: [
         '@plugins/vue-casl.js',
    ]
}
```

This is because I need to access `$auth.user` in my plugins.

All of this works good, except I can't find `$abilities` or `$can` in my Nuxt middleware.

---

PS: I am talking about this package: [@casl/vue](https://github.com/stalniy/casl/tree/master/packages/casl-vue)

Answer (score 1):

`$abilities` and `$can` should both be available as properties of the `context` object in your middleware, so you should be able to access them using `context.$foo`.

If you don't see it, it is probably because it was not injected properly. The plugin you registered in your `nuxt.config.js` should use `inject` to add `$can` to the global vue instance and make it available as a property of `this` and `context`. See the documentation for further detail: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/#inject-in-root--context